# jsTree - Sticky Node to Bottom of list

Tags: jquery, sorting, jstree

I would like a node of a specific type to always appear at the bottom of a parent node.  For example:

- Parent

  - Node Type A
  - Node Type A
  - Node Type A
  - Node Type B

Here, you would be able to drag and drop to move/manually sort nodes of Type A, but Type B would always appear below those nodes.

Is this possible and if so, can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
crrm : {
    move : {
        check_move : function (m) {
            var oldIndex = m.cop;
            var newIndex = m.cp;
            var oldParent = m.op;
            var newParent = m.np;

            if($("> ul > li[rel=typeB]", newParent).length == 0){ // no B Items in this folder
                return false;
            }
            // allow moving node only if "we are not going to place it to the end of the folder" or if "we are moving B node"
            return $("> ul > li", newParent).length != newIndex || m.o.attr("rel") == "typeB"; 
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Haven't tried it but looks accurate, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sort** plugin

```
plugins: [..., 'sort'],
sort: function(a, b) {
  if (a.rel == b.rel) return this.get_text(a) > this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1;
  else return a.rel > b.rel ? 1 : -1
}
```